# AWS AppSync query with nextToken returns same data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have the following query in my AppSync schema:

```
export const carsByUserGroupToCarsTable = /* GraphQL */ `query CarsByUserGroup($userGroup: String!, $limit: Int, $nextToken: String) {
    carsByUserGroup(userGroup: $userGroup, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        vin
        __typename
      }
      nextToken
      __typename
    }
  }
  ` as GeneratedQuery<
  APITypes.CarsByUserGroupQueryVariables,
  APITypes.CarsByUserGroupQuery
>;
```

This is my function that calls the query:

```
export const fetchCarsByGroup = async (userGroup: string, limit: int, nextToken: string | null | undefined) => {    
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(nextToken));
    
    try {
        const data = await client.graphql({
            query: customQueries.carsByUserGroupToCarsTable,
            variables: {
                userGroup,
                limit: 1, //hardcoded to 1 for test purposes
                nextToken
            },
        
        })

        return data;

    
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching cars:', error);
    }
};
```

After retrieving the initial data, I set my "nextToken" to a variable in the frontend. The user can then hit a "next page" button (the data is visualized in a table) with the new "nextToken". I have confirmed that the "nextToken" is correctly passed to the "fetchCarsByGroup" function.

However, the return of the request is the same data as the initial data with the same "nextToken" in the response.

This is what my resolver looks like:

Request:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Query",
    "index": "userGroup-index",
    "query": {
        "expression": "#userGroup = :userGroup",
        "expressionNames": {
            "#userGroup": "userGroup"
        },
        "expressionValues": {
            ":userGroup": {
                "S": "$ctx.args.userGroup"
            }
        }
    },
    "limit": $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.limit, 10)
    }
```

Response:

```
$util.toJson($ctx.result)
```

If I add the "nextToken" in the resolver right after the "limit" line like so:

```
    "nextToken":$util.defaultIfNullOrBlank($ctx.args.nextToken, null)
```

I get a MappingTemplate error saying "Unable to parse the JSON document".

So from my assumptions the error is the way my resolver is made. How do I pass the nextToken correctly in order to actually get a new query based on the nextToken?